# Правильно ли говорить " - это когда..."?

Tags: грамотная-речь

На уроках русского языка часто приходится описывать разные события и явления, и, когда кто-то из нашего класса начинает предложение, к примеру, так: "Явление - это когда...", наш преподаватель начинает ругать отвечающего за то, что нельзя использовать связку "это когда". На вопрос "Почему?" учитель отвечал:"Просто нельзя, и всё".

Как только я не пытался загуглить данное правило в русском языке, но ничего по этой теме я так и не смог узнать, поэтому решил спросить здесь об этом.

Правда ли нельзя использовать связку "это когда"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во всяком случае, такое построение предложения — не ошибка. Так говорят.

*«Литература – **это когда** читатель столь же талантлив, как и писатель...»* М. А. Светлов

Но… *Что дозволено Юпитеру, не дозволено быку.* Лучше на уроках постараться давать определения в более строгой форме.

Пособия по стилистике обычно характеризуют такие предложения, как разговорные.

Из [**Розенталя**](http://modernlib.net/books/rozental_ditmar_elyashevich/spravochnik_po_russkomu_yaziku_punktuaciya/read_21/):

> В разговорной речи встречаются сложные предложения такого типа: *Самая
> прочная дружба — **это когда** всё готов сделать для товарища; Самая
> интересная книга — **это когда** не знаешь, чем всё это кончится;
> Авторитет — **это когда** тебя боятся; Детское кино — **это когда**
> мультфильмы показывают; Счастье — **это когда** у тебя любимая
> работа.*
>
> Ср.: *Любовь — **это когда** кажется то, чего нет* (Ч.); *Самая
> поздняя осень — **это когда** от морозов рябина сморщится и станет,
> как говорят, «сладкой»* (Пришв.).
>
> В этих конструкциях придаточная
> часть сложноподчиненного предложения выполняет функцию сказуемого при
> подлежащем, выраженном формой именительного падежа существительного, и
> отделяется от него посредством тире.

Валгина в книге *"Активные процессы в современном русском языке"* пишет:

> Интересно, что такой разговорный тип предложения настолько прочно
> утвердился, что во многих газетных жанрах (репортаж, очерк, фельетон и
> др.) стал естественной формой выражения мысли… Тексты, допускающие
> подобные структуры, в стилистическом плане однотипны — это тексты,
> передающие непринужденный тон общения, живые, разговорные интонации,
> тексты, имитирующие сам процесс размышления, спонтанность в выражении
> мысли. Такие конструкции встречаются даже в научно-популярных статьях,
> в терминированной речи, что еще больше свидетельствует о широте
> распространения их в печати.

Из Валгиной:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Слово КОГДА может быть либо местоименным наречием времени, местоимением, либо союзом.

1. Союзным словом или союзом:

— Присоединяющим придаточное предложение к главному в составе сложноподчинённого — «Нам объявили, когда мы поедем на экскурсию. Это было, когда ты был маленьким»;

— Относящимся ко второму придаточному в сложноподчинённом предложении с двумя или несколькими придаточными, соединёнными союзом И, при однородном подчинении —«Мы отправились в поход, когда кончился дождь и когда выглянуло солнце»;

— Следующим сразу же после подчинительного союза ЧТО при последовательном подчинении и при этом есть слово ТОГДА: «Егор привел неожиданное для Левина замечание, что когда он жил у хороших господ, тогда он был своими господами доволен».

2. Неопределённым наречием при противопоставлении двух предложений или членов предложений посредством повторения: «Занимаюсь когда утром, когда вечером».
3. Неопределённым местоимением со значением *когда-нибудь*, *когда-либо*: «Спроси его, не бывал ли он когда в Витебске. Слыхал ли ты когда, чтоб мёртвые из гроба выходили».

Правда ли нельзя использовать связку "это когда"?

В конкретной фразе "Явление — это когда..." на роль местоименного прилагательного (*явление — какое? — это*) *ЭТО* не подходит, потому что в общем случае определяемое слово может быть и не среднего рода. И частицей, какую по определению можно опустить без потери смысла, *ЭТО* тоже нельзя назвать, и значения существительного (*он улыбнулся, это её удивило*) ему нельзя придать.

Впрочем, примеров использования связки в печати много, но среди них, к счастью, достаточно литературно правильных, например, таких:

> Но это ― когда имеем дело с частным сектором.
>
> Чего я не люблю, так это когда ты дураком прикидываешься.
>
> Так это когда было! — Это когда же?
>
> За редким исключением ― это когда ну совсем ничего нет.

Answer (score 1):

В принципе такая конструкция допустима, но использовать ее надо с осторожностью. Во-первых, она несет оттенок разговорности, а это плохо для ответов на уроках. Во-вторых, в школе требуются четкие формулировки, а построенное таким образом определение будет, скорее всего, неточным или даже неправильным. Возьмем приведенный в вопросе пример "Явление - это когда..." Я не смог придумать приемлемого продолжения для этой фразы.

Comment: Явление — это когда как бы да, но вроде не очень чтобы совсем уж.

Answer (score 1):

1) **Действительно, в школе  при ответах такие конструкции употреблять нежелательно.** Учитель может сказать: это неграмотно построенное предложение, но это не совсем так.

Конструкции с такой грамматикой, в которых придаточное предложение занимает позицию члена предложения (сказуемого), **допускаются**, такой пример приводится у Розенталя:

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92 3. Тире ставится перед словами это, это есть, значит, это значит, вот, присоединяющими сказуемое к подлежащему: **Самая поздняя осень — это когда** от морозов рябина сморщится и станет, как говорят, «сладкой» (Пришв.) — **в роли сказуемого выступает целое предложение;**

2) Но такие предложения более уместны **в публицистике, в художественной или разговорной речи.** В этому случае вместо определения какого-либо понятия предлагается его **описание,** раскрытие содержания в какой-то конкретной ситуации.

**А школьный ответ обычно ближе к научному стилю**, это не публицистика и не художественная речь.

3) **Пример**

Например, посмотрим в словаре определение слова ***счастье***

**СЧАСТЬЕ,**  1. Состояние высшей удовлетворённости жизнью, чувство глубокого довольства и радости, испытываемое кем-л.; внешнее проявление этого чувства. Семейное с. **4. в функц. сказ. (с придат. дополнит., с инф.).** Хорошо, удачно. С., у кого есть дети. Какое с., что мы вместе! Твоё с., что не было заморозка (разг.; повезло тебе).

(Обратим внимание **на корректное построение придаточных предложений**).

**А вот разговорный вариант:** Но счастье ― это когда всё внутри замирает, и время замирает, и кажется, вот она, настоящая жизнь. [Елена Голованова.2002]

Мы  видим, что синтаксис упрощен, в полном варианте: **счастье** ― это **состояние**, когда...

**Вот эти два момента** и определяют нежелательность подобных школьных ответов:

(1) **упрощенный синтаксис** с пропущенным **существительным,** которое по сути является **классификатором** определяемого предмета (явления) и поэтому  очень важно;

(2) **описание ситуации** вместо строгого определения (сначала надо дать определение, а уже потом раскрывать тему).

Comment: Как тут не вспомнить: *Счастье — это когда тебя понимают* ("Доживём до понедельника").